# Ubuntu 19.04 xrdp server terminating connection immediately

Tags: 19.04, xrdp

I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 into a VM. Installed xrdp via apt. Left everything on default: I believe this is how my 18.04 worked perfectly.

However, trying to connect to this VM via Remmina or Windows RDP client fails. Remmina shows a bit more because it attempts reconnection and so the result looks like this:

> The login screen appears, login dialog shows but then immediately the
>   connection is dropped.

This loops indefinitely with Remmina, but doesn't even show with Windows RDP client.

Tried the same with kubuntu 19.04 but result remains the same.

Edit:
Installing remmina from their next ppa fixes this issue and I can now connect to the host xrdp server:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade    <-- I had remmina installed from standard ubuntu repos
```

This is the only relevant change I did in the last few days. Will test how windows client works too, but if it does, something must have changed on the host as well...

Comment: would you be open to non-RDP solutions?

Comment: No, not particulary. Unless it offers better performance than noMachine or VNC

Comment: fair enough. just to clarify I understood that the guest was ubuntu/kubuntu but what is the host? also what app are you using in order to virtualize?

Comment: No, actually, I'm installing xrdp into guests: I want to be able to access them from multiple machines. The host is also an ubuntu, but that one doesn't have xrdp installed.